# How do I get this script to only run when a specific column is edited?

Tags: google-sheets, scripting

Based purely on the execution log it appears this script is running EVERY time anyone edits the sheet, but I only need it to run when column 3 or column 7 are edited.  What do I add into the script to tell it to do this?  I'm not super script literate so any help is greatly appreciated!!

```
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if( s.getName() == "FORD" ) {
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    if( r.getColumn() == 3) {
     
      var nextCell = r.offset(0,19);
      if( nextCell.getValue() === '' )
        nextCell.setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss');
    }
    
    if( r.getColumn() == 7) {
      var nextCell = r.offset(0,16);
      if( nextCell.getValue() === '' )
        nextCell.setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it weird that your code actually works on mine? If I understood your issue correctly, you want your script to be ran when columns 3 and 7. I don't see any issues on your script but I think this approach below should be better. We will use the `e` object to get your data.

#### Code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var s = e.source.getActiveSheet();

  if( s.getName() == "FORD" ) {
    var r = e.range;

    if( r.getColumn() == 3) {
      var nextCell = r.offset(0,19);
      if( nextCell.getValue() === '' )
        nextCell.setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss');
    }
    
    if( r.getColumn() == 7) {
      var nextCell = r.offset(0,16);
      if( nextCell.getValue() === '' )
        nextCell.setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss');
    }
  }
}
```

Practically the same logic your script does, but now, we do not get the data directly onto the sheet but the `onEdit` event object.

If you meant like the `onEdit` function should only be **TRIGGERED** during edits on column 3 and 7, that won't do.

`onEdit` function is triggered every time the sheet is edited manually, whatever range it is. We can only restrict the function on doing things by adding conditions but we can't practically stop triggering the function when a manual edit has been done.

It will always run on every manual edit, it is just a matter of restriction where we limit the function to do things based on what conditions we added. (Conditions such as running certain commands only if the sheet name is `FORD` and columns `3` or `7` are edited)

If I misunderstood your question, I sincerely apologize.

#### Edit:

I'm looking for other sources and it seems you can use `switch-case` instead of classic `if-else` statement as it is faster than the latter in large data. I've tested it and it seems it does have some significant difference in single tests. It will be significantly more faster in large data.

#### if-else:

[image: if-else]

#### switch-case:

[image: switch-case]

#### Test:

- The tests were the same on both `if-else` and `switch-case`.
- First 3 tests are edits on column 3, second 3 tests were on column 7 and last 3 were non-3/7 edits
- Run times are read bottom-up
- This actually varies per test but pasted these results as it seems to be close to the average.
- There are quotas that are in place and should be checked. See [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) for more details. You might need a paid subscription if you want more.

[image: quota]

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm ultimately looking for a way to reduce the number of times the script runs or the time it takes the script to run because I'm running into errors on my spreadsheet with timeouts or too many simultaneous invocations. The spreadsheet has a LOT of data and it's used as a real-time communication tool between about 25 users all at the same time, so lots of edits happening simultaneously. Do you think adding the "e" will help?

Comment: Hi @AnthonyIanucilli, I tried testing to see some alternatives, the edited answer might help you, kindly check. adding the e actually doesn't have significant difference based on my tests earlier. You might also take note of the quota in place. If you need more, you might need a paid subscription to increase your quota.

Comment: Hey @NaziA I tried throwing the edits into my script you suggested using the "e" and got this error message: TypeError: Cannot read property 'source' of undefined (line 2, file "Code"). What the heck does that mean?

Comment: hi @AnthonyIanucilli, you can't manually run onEdit on apps script especially when you use the parameter. It needs something that has been edited. it will only be triggered when a manual edit has been done on the sheet.