# Send an email from sheets when values are below a set value

Tags: google-sheets, scripting, spreadsheet

I'm trying to write a script for a google spreadsheet I use for inventory tracking.
When the on hand value gets below the minimum inventory value, I want an email to trigger that includes the part number and the quantity I need to make to get back to our minimum inventory quantity, ie. "PN Needs # Made". I've had success with just sending an email for one value, but I cannot figure out how to have the script look over a range without repeating the script for every row.
[image: example table]
The image is a screenshot of what I'm working on. For example, since V1276 needs one more piece made to meet the min. inv. qt., I'd like the email to tell me "V1276 Needs 1 Made". The sample code I've been playing with:

```
    function CheckParts() {
    var minVal = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Master List").getRange("H2");
    var valule = minVal.getValue();
    if (valule < minVal){
    // Fetch the email address
    var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("B2");
    var emailAddress = emailRange.getValues();
  
    // Send Alert Email.
    var message = 'You need to make ' + monthSales; // Second column
    var subject = 'Low Parts Alert';
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include your script so we could understand where we are coming from? So we know what to modify in your code. The approach is different depending on what you need. But based on your question, (most likely) you run the function manually. This is just a guess since we don't have a clear picture on what your script is.

Comment: I just edited the posting to include my test script, I hope that helps.

Comment: I have provided an answer below. Check if it works on you @benthelemon.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to run it manually. If you want, then have this modification:

#### Script:

```
function CheckParts() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Master List");
  var lastRow = dataSheet.getLastRow();
  // Get A2:I values
  var values = dataSheet.getRange(2, 1, lastRow - 1, 9).getValues();
  var emailAddress = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("B2").getValue();
  // Filter rows where H > I
  values.filter(e => e[7] > e[8]).forEach(e => {
    var pN = e[0];
    var description = e[1];
    var minInv = e[7];
    var currInv = e[8];
    // Send a more detailed email
    var message = `Currently, we only have ${currInv} items of "${description}".\nTo reach minimum inventory quantity of ${minInv}, you need to make ${minInv-currInv} additional item.`;
    var subject = `Low Parts Alert for ${pN}`;
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  });
}
```

#### Data Sample:

[image: sample]

#### Output:

[image: output1]
[image: output2]

#### Testing after changing I3 to 2:

[image: output3]

#### Note:

- Script above will check all rows that satisfies the condition `H > I`. If it falls under that, then it will send an email for each row.
- There is also an option to automatically send an email once it detects that you either edited H or I column values and it satisfies the condition (e.g. H > I). For that, we need an `onEdit` installed trigger. If you prefer this `onEdit` approach, mention it below so I can provide it for you.

Comment: Thank you for the solution, that's very helpful! Can you give some guidance/an example with the `onEdit` approach?

Comment: hi @benthelemon, you can try and check [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66693886/14606045) out.